# Find unique value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a Pandas column, on each row of the column there are multiple values. I would like to obtain a set of unique values in the whole column. For example:

From:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|                  Column                   |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 300000,50000,500000,100000,1000000,200000 |
| 100000,1000000,200000,300000,50000,500000 |
|                                       ... |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

To:

```
+--------+
| Column |
+--------+
|  50000 |
| 100000 |
| 200000 |
| 300000 |
|    ... |
+--------+
```

Thank you very much

Comment: It is a single columns Try `df['Column'].apply(set, 1)`?

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: @Chris the apply set gives me the set of each row. But it won't give me the unique value for all columns

Comment: @cs95 Order doesn't really matter. It can be sorted at the very end as part of the postprocessing procedure

Comment: So you mean you have multiple columns in a similar fashion? perhaps updating your sample data would make the question more understandable then :)

Comment: So, just so we understand. Is each entry in the column a string of comma separated numbers?

Comment: @Chris I only have one column, but every entry is a string list

Comment: @cs95 Yes it is comma separated number. I want to obtain a set of unique value of the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure pandas solution should be slowier, if large data - idea is create Series by `split` and `stack`, remove duplicated, convert to integers and sorting:

```
df = (df['Column'].str.split(',', expand=True)
                  .stack()
                  .drop_duplicates()
                  .astype(int)
                  .sort_values()
                  .reset_index(drop=True)
                  .to_frame('col'))
print (df)
       col
0    50000
1   100000
2   200000
3   300000
4   500000
5  1000000
```

Or use set comprehension with flatten splitted lists, convert to integers, sorted and last pass to Dataframe - solution should be faster in large DataFrame:

```
#solution working if no missing values, no Nones
L = sorted(set([int(y) for x in df['Column'] for y in x.split(',')]))

#solution1 (working with NaN)s
L = sorted(set([int(y) for x in df['Column'] if x == x for y in x.split(',')]))

#solution2 (working with None)s
L = sorted(set([int(y) for x in df['Column'] if x != None for y in x.split(',')]))

#solution3 (working with NaN, None)s
L = sorted(set([int(y) for x in df['Column'] if pd.notna(x) for y in x.split(',')]))

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':L})
print (df)
       col
0    50000
1   100000
2   200000
3   300000
4   500000
5  1000000
```

Comment: I am not sure but I can't get the second one running

Comment: @Winston - Maybe some missing values, can you try `L = sorted(set([int(y) for x in df['Column'] if x == x for y in x.split(',')]))` ?

Comment: Yes you are right. I need to add dropna() at the end of df['Column'].

Solution #3 works

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at the other question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640228/efficient-way-to-do-the-pandas-dataframe-column-lookup
This question is just part of the goal I want to achieve (if grouping is the way)

Comment: @Winston - Sure, but give me some time.

Comment: I guess the groupby solution would be good enough. But I still have problem finding the right code to do that transformation

Comment: @Winston - there are missing values ?

Comment: @Winston - added solution, but not sure if working if missing data, please test it.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
>>> data = {'column' : ["300000,50000,500000,100000,1000000,200000","100000,1000000,200000,300000,50000,500000"]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df.column.str.split(',').explode().astype(int).drop_duplicates().sort_values(ascending=True)
```

Outputs:

```
    column
0    50000
1   100000
2   200000
3   300000
4   500000
5  1000000
```

Comment: Good Attempt @luigigi

Comment: @Vishnudev yes but it assumes the data to be a column of lists; OP says they're not. Good attempt, but still not completely right. (not the downvoter)

Comment: Not sure why I was downvoted. Just stating facts. :)

Comment: Yes, it should be data = {'column' : "300000,50000,500000,100000,1000000,200000","100000,1000000,200000,300000,50000,500000"}

Comment: Updated @Winston